My desktop automatically shuts down when I want it to go to suspend mode
Problem. My desktop automatically shuts down when I want it to go to suspend mode.
I have configured 'Power' as

'Empty screen after 10 minutes'
'Automatic suspend' 'On', 'Delay 15 minutes'
This has been working fine for many years with different versions of Ubuntu. Since a while my Desktop shuts down instead of going to suspend and has to be started manually. Maybe it happened after uppgrading fromm 20 to 22.
To test it I have configured 'Suspend- and shutoff button' as
*'Suspend'
When pushing the button it goes to suspend mode and can be woke up with the mouse or the keyboard.
Question:
How can I make it automatically go to Standby mode instead of shutting down?

